# Business time with several joins (Temporal logic in db2)

Tags: sql, db2, bi-temporal

I am working with DB2 and its feature "*Temporal logic*" (if you are interesting in the topic - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1204db2temporaldata/index.html gives an introduction). I got one question about an issue which I cannot understand so far:

This example will work perfectly fine:

```
SELECT * FROM policy 
FOR BUSINESS_TIME FROM '2009-01-01' TO '2011-01-01'
```

But if I want to join more tables, I get errors that the syntax is wrong. And there are no examples (read: I cannot find examples) of how to do it.

Yes, I know how to avoid this "feature", and make it work with sub select. And even between `date_from` and `date_to` won't help here. Because this `BUSINESS_TIME` is not equal `date_to`.

In my case, something like:

```
where'2009-01-01' <='2009-01-01'<'2011-01-01'
```

doesn't work.

**Update** in DB2 should be like this:

```
 where '2009-01-01'<='2009-01-01'
   and '2009-01-01'<'2011-01-01'
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining also works - this is one of my examples joining two tables on BUSINESS TIME

```
SELECT u.name, u.BUSINESS_START, u.BUSINESS_END
     , d.name, d.BUSINESS_START, d.BUSINESS_END
     , max(u.BUSINESS_START, d.BUSINESS_START) as Result_BUSINESS_START
     , min(u.BUSINESS_END, d.BUSINESS_END) as Result_BUSINESS_END
  FROM Praesident_USA FOR business_time 
                      FROM '1970-01-01' TO CURRENT DATE U
 INNER JOIN KANZLER_D FOR business_time 
                      FROM '1970-01-01' TO CURRENT DATE D
    ON d.BUSINESS_START <= u.BUSINESS_END 
       AND d.BUSINESS_END >= u.BUSINESS_START
```

I hope you find this helpful for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelTiefenbacher , but probably I just wasn't really correct in my question. For example, If I would have several dimensions and use your select, I get all of them between '1970-01-01' and CURRENT DATE, But I wanna get only one, particulr. Well, we can change  it

        FOR business_time FROM '2018-06-15' TO '2018-06-16' 

if I would need something like '2018-06-15' between start_dt and end_dt.
BUT! I was so surprised, when I have got row start_dt = '2018-06-15' and as well another row which is equal min(start_dt ) or first loaded date.

Comment: Only a specific date you would probable use 
" as of  '1970-01-01'  D" or whatever date you need. But I am sorry I do not understand yor comment. Maybe you can rephrase what you need or what your question is